# securing iphone + web app

Tags: iphone

I have an iphone app that retrieves and send data to a server that uses python.
What measures could i take in order to prevent security risks?
I an not handling extremely sensitive data but i wouldn't want people sniffing the contents.

Is using SSL enough to prevent most risks?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have super-sensitive data, you can also use [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) messages in order to query your server. I've done this with several projects before.

The message sent to the server may be a little more heavy-weight but is a viable option if you don't want to go with getting a SSL certificate.

Answer (score 2):

SSL should be sufficient. It's also a good idea to store the user's password (if you need one to login) inside the Keychain. Btw, don't send anything to the server in a QueryString, always do it with a post, otherwise the SSL won't do much to help you.